# What kind of component is needed for this switch functionality?

Tags: switches

I need a button (or a button couple) that acts as a switch in emergency such that when one pushes the button, the +12V supply line below becomes an open circuit even he releases the button. But I also want the user (after fixing the issue etc.) can push the button (or button couple) and the supply line is closed and device is powered again.

[image]

What type of button/switch or latch can provide such functionality?

Answer (score 3):

Not surprisingly, these are called "emergency stop switches" and they are [readily available](https://www.amazon.ca/emergency-stop-switch/s?k=emergency%20stop%20switch).

For safety reasons, however, most are typically reset not by a second push, but by twisting or pulling instead. However dual-button and rocker variants are also available, although they are usually more expensive, especially those with built-in fuses.